# Creating an Outlook Appointment doesn´t add recipients

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I have a function which creates an appointment in Outlook. My problem is, that it does not add any recipients. I tried it with a CheckedListBox and with strings only (hardcoded), but it does not work.
The appointment itselfs gets created, but with no recipients..

That´s my code:

```
  Dim app As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application
        Dim appt As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem

        app = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application
        appt = app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem)
        appt.Subject = tbBetreff.Text
        appt.Body = tbInhalt.Text
        appt.Location = tbOrt.Text

        For Each itemChecked In cbContacts.CheckedItems
            Dim sentTo As Outlook.Recipients = appt.Recipients
            Dim sentInvite As Outlook.Recipient
            sentInvite = sentTo.Add(itemChecked.ToString())
            sentInvite.Type = Outlook.OlMeetingRecipientType.olRequired
            sentTo.ResolveAll()
        Next

        appt.Start = Convert.ToDateTime("24.07.2020 13:00:00")
        appt.End = Convert.ToDateTime("24.07.2020 14:00:00")
        appt.ReminderSet = True
        appt.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 30

        appt.Save()
```

Do you see the problem?
Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to set the [AppointmentItem.MeetingStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.meetingstatus) property which sets an `OlMeetingStatus` constant specifying the meeting status of the appointment. Then you can add attendees.

The following sample code programmatically creates an appointment, sets various properties, and sends the appointment to request a meeting. CreateAppt uses the CreateItem` method to create an AppointmentItem object. It sets the MeetingStatus property of the AppointmentItem to olMeeting to indicate the appointment as a meeting request, and sets a required attendee, an optional attendee, and a meeting location as a resource. The example then displays and sends the appointment item.

```
Sub CreateAppt() 
 Dim myItem As Object 
 Dim myRequiredAttendee, myOptionalAttendee, myResourceAttendee As Outlook.Recipient 
 
 Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem) 
 myItem.MeetingStatus = olMeeting 
 myItem.Subject = "Strategy Meeting" 
 myItem.Location = "Conf Rm" 
 myItem.Start = #9/24/2020 1:30:00 PM# 
 myItem.Duration = 90 
 Set myRequiredAttendee = myItem.Recipients.Add("Eugene Astafiev") 
 myRequiredAttendee.Type = olRequired 
 Set myOptionalAttendee = myItem.Recipients.Add("Kevin Kennedy") 
 myOptionalAttendee.Type = olOptional 
 Set myResourceAttendee = myItem.Recipients.Add("Conf Rm All Stars") 
 myResourceAttendee.Type = olResource 
 myItem.Display 
End Sub
```